# How to Edit/Update Nant script

Tags: service, nant

I need to update an Nant script automatically by fetching some data from database. The solution I can think of is to be done through a service which fetches the data from DB and update the Nant script.
Can this be done? If yes, how?

Comment: You might benefit more if you provided an example of what you're trying to do :)

Answer (score 1):

In theory, if you need to change how the script works then you could create a program to generate the NAnt build file, run it with the `exec` task, `include` that file and then call a target.

That seems a bit over-complicated though.  I suppose it depends on how much the script will change based on the data.

If the data is simply configuration, then you can use the data to set properties in your build script (either by the same mechanism above, or by creating a custom task to create a property value based on the result of a SQL statement).  Then use those properties to determine control flow in the build script using standard things like `if` statements and `foreach` loops.

I don't think that there's anything built-in that will do this for you, but custom tasks are very easy to create if you can program.

Answer (score 0):

If you update/edit a nant script it does not change the current execution. Instead you can generate .build files and execute them via `<nant>` [task](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/nant.html), for example using a `<foreach>` loop or `<style>` xsl-transformation. An alternative would be to write a small `<script>`, in particular if you can program it comfortably in C#. If you wish more specific answers more information would be helpful. (database used, what tools you can use to extract data)